# Simple Map D3 JSON

Tags: json, d3.js, choropleth

I am trying to built a choropleth on a timezone world map. I came across this library which makes creating choropleths on Topojson files really easy, http://code.minnpost.com/simple-map-d3/ .

I have two JSON files with me: one is a topojson to create the timezone world map and the other a simple JSON which would be used to define the color and tooltips for the map. My question is that can we upload two JSON files using the simple map D3 library? or does it cater to only topojson files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you are trying to have two separate JSON files for that but I believe the library only takes in TopoJSON files.

If you want to set your own custom colors though, you can set the `styles` attribute as they show in one of their examples. You can have this formatted in a JSON object and include it as long as it adhere's to the structure shown in their examples, but I don't see why you would need to make its own separate file for it.

> There are a number of style configuration options that will be set on SVG objects. It is suggested to use CSS for these sorts of thing, but there are use-cases for direct setting of the styles. The following are the available styles:
>
> - `styles`: Styles for each map feature. The fill will be overrided if color is on.
> - `stylesHover`: Styles to apply to hover state of map feature.
> - `stylesBackground`: Styles for a background container.
> - `stylesLegendContainer`: Styles for legend container.
> - `stylesLegendTitleText`: Styles for legend title text.
> - `stylesLegendText`: Styles for each legend item text.
> - `stylesLegendSwatch`: Styles for each legend item color swatch.
> - `stylesGraticule`: Styles for the graticule.
> - `stylesGlobe`: Styles for the globe.